# Change Window color periodically when data from network arrives

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this little program which listens on a port. What I want to achieve is, when data from network arrives, it should change window color to that data. How should I modify my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import Tk
import time
import socket

window = Tk()
window.geometry("266x208")
window.title("Claculator")
window.configure(background='#ffffff')
window.mainloop() 


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data #here comes the data color and it should call window color change
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

Comment: This is quite a quandary. `window.mainloop()` will run indefinitely as long as your window remains open. The `while 1:` loop will run indefinitely as long as there is more data to receive. You usually can't run two infinite loops at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried the `.after()` method? [Check this out](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method). If not, give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an infinite loop for the connection and for the Tkinter GUI, and you can't have 2 loops in a single thread. The best solution would be to start a new thread for one of them. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import Tk
import time
import socket
import threading

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

class Connection(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
        s.listen(1)

        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Connection address:', addr
        while 1:
            data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not data: break
            print "received data:", data #here comes the data color and it should call window color change
            self.window.config(background=data)
            self.window.update()
            conn.send(data)  # echo
        conn.close()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("266x208")
window.title("Claculator")
window.configure(background='#ffffff')
thread = Connection()
thread.window = window
thread.start() #start the connection loop
window.mainloop() #start Tkinter's loop
```

(totally untested).